# snort -A unsock

Tags: linux

Всем привет. Настраиваю snort. Есть опция, где можно получать данные из unix socket. Я включил эту опцию на старте, опцией -A unsock. После запуска, unix socket не создался. Или я его не нашёл. В исходниках было написано, что файл имеет имя *.SNORT.sock. Но его во всей я не нашёл. Как правильно надо делать?

Comment: Я нашёл что за это отвечает control, и в пакетном менеджере ubuntu эту опцию при создании пакета не включили.

Comment: А всё решил проблему. Главное не забыть установить правильные настройки в конфиг файле, после установки из исходников.